# Why do we need an even number between $x$ and $y$ in Pythagorean triple where $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I needed to know about Pythagorean triple in details. So I started searching in Google.

Suppose that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are relatively prime and $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$. Then I've found an interesting fact that, among $x, y$, and $z$, only $x$ or $y$ can be even. $z$ can never be.

I searched for this and haven't found the reason behind this. Would anybody please tell me the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be overkill.

if $z^2 = x^2+ y^2$ is even if and only if $x , y $ are both same parity and if $x,y,z $ are relatively prime that parity must be odd.

Let $x =2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$ and $z=2c $ and $(2a+1)^2 + (2b+1)^2 =4c^2$ so $4a^2 + 4a +4b^2 + 4b +2 = 4c^2$

So, $a^2 + a + b^2  + b + \frac 12 = c^2$.  Hence, $a,b,c $ can not all be integers.  So no integer pythagorean triple $x,y,z $ exists where $x,y$ are both odd.

And as $x,y$ can't be both even and relative prime to $z $ (which would also be even) primitive pythagorean triples must be such $x,y$ are opposite parity and $z $ is odd.

No triples, primitive or otherwise, can have $x,y $ both odd.  $x,y,z $ can all be even, but such a triple is, of course, not primitive.

Comment: great answer. Such that, now I'm thinking I should have caught that point. Thanks a lot. Your "Let" portion has made everything easy for me.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x,y$ and $z$ are relatively prime, $x$ and $y$ cannot both be even, for then $z$ would be even as well. So we just have to rule out the possibility that $x$ and $y$ are both odd.

To do so, recall that the only squares mod $4$ are $0$ and $1$. Hence if $x$ and $y$ are odd, then $x^2+y^2\equiv 2$ (mod $4$), but on the other hand $z^2\equiv 0,1$ (mod $4$), so we cannot have $x^2+y^2=z^2$ in this case.

Therefore exactly one of $x,y$ is odd, and then $z$ must be odd as well.

Comment: I have got the reason why both (x,y) are not even but I've not got why square of both odd can't make square of even. I'll be really grateful if you write more. :( It seems interesting to me, so I'm trying to know this. :)

Comment: If $n$ is even then $n^2\equiv 0$ (mod $4$), while if $n$ is odd then $n^2\equiv 1$ (mod $4$). So if we add two squares of odd integers, the result is $\equiv 2$ (mod $4$), so cannot be the square of an integer.

Comment: Oh, most probably now I got it ... :) Thanks a lot ...